# Flask url_for http instead of https

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, flask, https

I have a website that has these URLs: `example.net` and `track.example.net`. While the homepage on `example.net` is SSL encrypted and works fine, the subdomain is only partially encrypted.

The certificate is valid for both domains. I found that the site file links generated by `url_for` are returning `http://example.net/static/js/scripts.js` on the subdomain pages. On the homepage, however, making the same `url_for` call returns `/static/js/scripts.js`

I have tried adding `app.config['PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME'] = 'https'` in the `__init__.py` file, however this had no effect.

When I manually change the inspect element URLs to `https` the site seems to work fine.

I found that adding these parameters to the `url_for` function does in fact return the `https` version: `_external=True, _scheme='https'`. However, this is very inconvinient as I have hundreds of `url_for` calls throughout the program.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all requests.

```
import functools
url_for = functools.partial(url_for, _scheme='https')
```